# Using Blowfish class to set up a login. Error being observed Fatal error: Class 'Bcrypt' not found

Tags: php

I'm new to php and mysql. I am trying to create an encrypted login using blowfish. I have used the following code and keep getting an error:

**Fatal error: Class 'Bcrypt' not found in**

I'm sorry if this is simple, but I'm a newbie and checked the site and google for a simple explanation.

Code:

```
require('blowfish.php');

$bcrypt= new Bcrypt(4);

$hash= $crypt->hash('mypass123');
echo $hash;
```

Have tried with blowfish.class.php but to no avail

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1.) Is the file in the right path? (In this case in the same path as this script)

2.) Is the Class in the blowfish.php file called "Bcrypt"?

EDIT: Also test if blowfish is enabled: 
http://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/blowfish-crypt/